# Programmatically auto layout an array of images in various sizes

Tags: swift, uiimageview, autolayout, swift4, ios-autolayout

I'm making a 2d puzzle game (grid/board) Sokoban if anyone has heard of it, below is the code. I am looking for a way to display the board (array of images).

```
func makeLevel() {
        var cellImageView: [[UIImageView]] = []
        var floorImageView: [[UIImageView]] = []
        let cellWidth = 35
        let cellHeight = 35

        let x0 = 190 - 4 * cellWidth
        let y0 = 300 - 4 * cellHeight

        let imageForCellMarker: [Character: UIImage] = [
            ".": UIImage(named: "poopgoal30x30")!,
            "#": UIImage(named: "wall30x30")!,
            "$": UIImage(named: "box30x30")!,
            "@": UIImage(named: "cat30x30")!,
            "£": UIImage(named: "box30x30")!,
            "&": UIImage(named: "cat30x30")!,
            ]

        //Floor
        for y in 0..<rows {
            floorImageView.append([])
            for x in 0..<cols {
                let image = UIImage(named: "floor30x30")!
                let frame = CGRect(x: x0 + x * cellWidth, y: y0 + y * cellHeight,         width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
                let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
                imageView.image = image
                floorImageView[y].append(imageView)
                view.addSubview(imageView)
            }
        }

        //Level
        for y in 0 ..< rows {
            cellImageView.append([])
            for x in 0 ..< cols {
                let image = imageForCellMarker[gameBoard[y][x]]
                let frame = CGRect(x: x0 + x * cellWidth, y: y0 + y * cellHeight, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
                let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame)
                imageView.image = image
                cellImageView[y].append(imageView)
                view.addSubview(imageView)
            }
        }
    }
```

Since the board is going to be in various rows and columns depends on the level, so I can't really set it to a constant position in the view. Hence, is there any of you kind swift experts would show me how I could auto layout the grid so it fits on all devices?

Comment: Part of your issue will be orientation... For example, how would you want the "floor" image to look on an iPhone in Portrait orientation vs Landscape orientation? Or, more accurately, in Compact-Width / Regular-Height vs Regular-Width / Compact Height? You can manage "grid" like functionality with auto-layout... but you need to describe / show what you *expect* as a result.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/zHLOS This is what it looks like at the moment. But in landscape mode, it just stays on the left hand side. For a bigger level it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/ao0gm ultimately what I want is no matter what phone size, portrait or landscape it should stay in the centre.

Comment: Google snapkit. It helps to programmatically implement auto layout for multiple devices

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using auto-layout and constraints, instead of absolute values... that would avoid having to manually calculate sizes and positions.

To get your *current* code to center your "game area," you can change these two lines:

```
    let x0 = 190 - 4 * cellWidth
    let y0 = 300 - 4 * cellHeight
```

to (I'm assuming the `4` above is the number of rows and columns):

```
    let x0 = Int(view.frame.size.width) / 2 - cols * cellWidth / 2
    let y0 = Int(view.frame.size.height) / 2 - rows * cellHeight / 2
```

So...

```
cols * cellWidth      // equals the full width of the game area
rows * cellHeight     // equals the full height of the game area

cols * cellWidth / 2    // equals one-half the width of the game area
rows * cellHeight / 2   // equals one-half the height of the game area

Int(view.frame.size.width) / 2   // equals the horizontal center of the view
Int(view.frame.size.height) / 2  // equals the vertical center of the view
```

to get the game area to center in the view, set the starting X to the center X - one-half the width of the game area, and set the starting Y to the center Y - one-half of the height of the game area.

This will center your game area, regardless of device. For larger devices, though, it will be a small area in the center of the total view... so you would need to calculate the `cellWidth` and `cellHeight` values based on the size of the screen / view.